# firebase cloud function won't store cookie in the browser cookies

Tags: node.js, angular, cookies, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a single login for two angular apps in the same domain
I've follow this guide [Manage Session Cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies)

Here's my cloud function code

index.js

```
app.post('/sessionLogin', (req, res) => {
  // Get the ID token passed and the CSRF token.
  const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();
  const csrfToken = req.body.csrfToken.toString();

  // Guard against CSRF attacks.
  if(req.cookies){
    if (csrfToken !== req.cookies.csrfToken) {
      res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
      return;
    }
  }

  // Set session expiration to 5 days.
  const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
  admin.auth()
    .createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn })
    .then(
      (sessionCookie) => {
        // Set cookie policy for session cookie.
        const options = {
          maxAge: expiresIn,
           httpOnly: true,
            secure: true,
            domain: "domain.com" };
            res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private');
        res.cookie('__session', sessionCookie, options);
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: 'success' }));
      
        console.log("res : ", res);

      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
      }
    );
});
```

the console.log(res) shows that the __session is added, but i find nothing in browser cookies section, and of course when i try to get it with req.cookies.__session nothing found.

Comment: Have you tried following the guide further and verifying the cookies? What is the output?

Comment: Yes i followd the guide, but req.cookies.__session is undefined, no cookies with name __session is set, i really don't know what i am missing